# Getting error while running Azure release pipeline for Azure Data Factory Continuous Deployment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

Getting error while running Azure release pipeline for Azure Data Factory Continuous Deployment, whenever I am updating the event trigger name in the source (Dev) Azure Data Factory.

I have created a release pipeline in which I am overwriting the parameter with new values, It is working fine and all the changes from Dev ADF to prod are working and deploying.

I am getting error or my release pipeline getting failed whenever I am updating the Name of event trigger in Dev pipeline.

Is ther any solution for the above problem??

Comment: Hi Asif Khan; could you specify precisely what error you get?

Comment: Yes @VinceBowdren, Basically when I have created the release, at that time there were some overwrite parameter for triggers, but when ever I am updating the trigger name in ADF, release pipeline will contain old trigger name as well in overwrite parameter, and then it show errror that this trigger parameter in not contain in main template file, the available parameters are this this this (New updated parameter)